# $k$-homogeneous function

Tags: analysis, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $k$-homogeneous function $$f(tx)=t^kf(x), \forall \ t\in \mathbb{R}, \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^m.$$

I proved that each derivative $f^{(j)}, 1\leq j \leq k$ is $(k-j)$-homogeneous and that $f^{(k)}$ is constant. Now, i must prove that $$f^{(j)}(v_1,\dots,v_j)=\frac{1}{(k-j)!}f^{(k)}(0)\cdot (\underbrace{x,\dots,x}_{k-j},v_1,\dots,v_j).$$

I know that i can write $$f^{(j)}(tx) = t^{k-j}f^{(j)}(x)$$ but after this i don't really now what to do.

Comment: Are you sure about the last equation? If we plug in $x=0$ you get $f^{(k)}(0)=t^k f^{(k)}(0)$ which yields $1 = t^k$ which certainly isn't true.

Comment: If you use $f^{(k)}$ you get $f^k(tx)=f^k(x)$, so your equation is not true

Comment: Oh, I oversaw that. But for all other $j<k$ we get $f^{(j)}(0) = t^{k-j}f^{(j)}(0)$ and therefore $t^{k-j}=1$ for all $1\leq j \leq k$, especially this yields $t=1$. So something in the last equation has to be changed so that we can solve the problem.